# iOS custom shortcut in/out value

Tags: ios, swift, input, shortcut

I've created a custom shortcut in my app which can be triggered from within the Shortcuts app. However I wonder if there is a documentation on how to allow input values (such as integers, or media etc).
I see that the instagram app allows passing media content to its shortcut. Is this proprietary to Apple selected apps, or is there a way I can achieve this as well with my own app?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a duplicate of this Question: 
[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52548507/how-to-create-a-siri-intent-that-accepts-input-passed-from-user)

At the moment it seems like, there is no way to have a in/out value. It`s only for Apple built shortcuts.