# How can we get Text that we Speak from Siri?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I am writing an app that include a scenario where I want a search using Siri like "Hey Siri, APP_NAME PHRASE" give any phrase using Siri and I need that PHRASE as Text to my app. I tried with custom intent but no luck. Is it possible to achieve with custom intent??

Comment: What code have you used so far? Make the problem easily reproducible by providing all the necessary code

Comment: You could have a look at [Building a Speech-to-Text App Using Speech Framework](https://www.appcoda.com/siri-speech-framework/)

Comment: @chirag90 there is requirement of using siri only, so is it possible to achieve using siri?

Comment: @chirag90 It's Siri system Intent as name INRequestRideIntent , and it's for Ride , In Custom Intent Siri not provide text or anything

Comment: All he wants is how to get text spoken using siri in my custom intent, In handle method if i can get the text spoken at siri i can use it for further process. Can access any property that can give me resolved text by siri.

Comment: finally after lot of  r & d  , i got the solution that Dynamic user input is supported in IOS 13

Comment: @josolution Hey could you please give some reference how did you able to do that?

Comment: @josolution can please provide some reference or demo how did you solve this using siri?
i'm looking for same implementation.

Comment: @Krunal Here is the link from where you can get some help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52548507/how-to-create-a-siri-intent-that-accepts-input-passed-from-user and Furthermore help you can download Apple Soup chef app project and it's linked here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/soup_chef_accelerating_app_interactions_with_shortcuts